# Is there a way to have .NET Framework code in a .NET Core library?

Tags: .net-core

We have a commercial library that I am working to port to .NET Core. There are a couple of calls in it I want to retain to use only if running in .NET standard. (For the curious, one set is to read a file on a Windows server that requires credentials to access.)

Is there:

1. A call that will tell me if I am running under .NET Standard vs. .NET Core.
2. Is there a way to have a class that is only going to be instantiated/called if running under standard, but the DLL will still load fine under Core?

[Also asked on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d96aa6e0-9238-4d76-9679-7cbd852f7000/what-is-the-best-way-to-have-net-framework-net-core-specific-code?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: So, you basically want to decide at runtime, whether your .NET Core code is running on Windows or not, right?

Comment: Your title does not match the body. Is it about having code, or running code?

Comment: @Marcel Correct, at run time if I am running in Core I return cannot read \\server\share files requiring credentials. If .net standard, I read them.

Comment: Your class at runtime will never run in .NET standard, if you port it to .NET Core. It will only ever run in .NET Core. That is the point of porting to .NET Core, isn't it?

Comment: @nvoigt No. We're a commercial library we provide to hundreds of thousands of users. Some are on .NET Standard, some are on .NET Core. I'd prefer to have a single distributable that works for both.

Comment: Ah... you cannot? It's either a .NET Standard library, or not. If you port it to .NET Core, only .NET Core projects can use them. Alternatively you can have multiple targetframeworks and deliver nuget packages with multiple libraries, one compiled for each target.

Comment: BTW: one cannot be "on .NET Standard". The library might be .NET standard, but the end result executing assembly as to be either Full Framework or Core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since what you describe, having a single nuget package and being able to specify different behaviours or dependencies depending on the framework the nuget package is installed into, can only be reached through [Multi Targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks) I will assume you are doing that or will be doing it.

Once you have [specified target frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-target-frameworks), you have pre-defined variables to use in precompile blocks:

```
#if NETFRAMEWORK
    // use full framework class here. You were installed into a full framework app or library
#elif NETCOREAPP
    // use .NET Core class here. You were installed into a .NET Core app or library
#else NETSTANDARD
    // uh... okay... you were installed into another .NET Standard library, 
    // we still have no idea where *that* might be installed... help? 
    // Maybe make it configurable after all?
#endif
```

Comment: Ok, so no single DLL then. We need to conditionally build for the standard framework or .NET core. Not a biggie, just a bit of a pain. ps - Agree with you on Monica.

Answer (score 1):

.NET Standard is not a runtime, it is a set of APIs that a runtime must implement in order to be compatible. So basically this allows people to have a library target .NET Standard and have one code-base that will run in all supported runtimes because it is guaranteed that those runtimes will have an implementation for those APIs.

.NET Standard doesn't have implementation at all, it just defines a set contract of APIs which is used at compile time, but at runtime the APIs used will be the ones in the runtime the consumer decided to target their application for.

A better runtime detection would be to use [RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescriptor](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription) APIs. We do that for our framework tests to know what we're running our tests on: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Common/tests/CoreFx.Private.TestUtilities/System/PlatformDetection.cs#L21

You could also achieve this via reflection by doing something like: `typeof(string).Assembly`... if the assembly is `System.Private.CoreLib` you're on .NET Core, if it is `mscorlib`, you're in .NET Framework.