# What is the best way to have both .NET Framework & .NET Core specific code

Tags: .net-core

We have a .NET Framework commercial library that we are revising to run on .NET Core **also.**

Which leads to the question, how do we handle the code that is .NET Framework only and .NET Core only? How do I build this? I've thought of the following:

1. The code does a runtime check in each method and calls the appropriate code. This may not work because it will try to load references from the other platform when the class is first instantiated.
2. Have a wrapper class and that class' code will call to the appropriate class depending on the platform. This I think would avoid the loading non-existent packages issue.
3. Use reflection to create & call the appropriate classes. Create two WindwardPlatform.dll libraries, each with identical public classes, version number, & strong naming.
4. Something else???

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59751879/is-there-a-way-to-have-standard-net-code-in-a-net-core-library) which speaks on how to deploy. The question above is on how to structure the platform dependent code.

**More details:**

We have a commercial software product we sell. It currently runs on .NET Framework and we are porting it to run on .NET Core also. It is composed of 12 DLLs and 3 EXEs.

I've found 3 methods (maybe 4 if I can't work around another) that are .NET Framework specific. They're code to read a file from a \server\share using credentials, either of the logged in user or explicitly provided. All the rest of our code is compatible with .NET Core 3.1.

Two of the DLLs out of the 12 need these readFile() methods. So they need to call (they are all static methods) this platform specific code. Which in the case of .NET Core will do nothing at present. But in the future we may come up with a way to provide this functionality.

Compiling all this is trivial. Adding #if clauses around the code is also easy. The question is what do I build? I'd like to have one set of DLLs that people download (via NuGet) regardless of platform. And that could be done using reflection.

But the question is, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does library heavily dependent on .NET Framework features which not supported by .NET Standard?

Comment: @Fabio Good question. No. It looks like it will be 4 methods.

Comment: Conditional compilation in SDK styled projects, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if#remarks

Comment: @LexLi And with the conditional compilation approach, do I create a WindwardFramework.dll and WindwardCore.dll, where both have the same signature  and the other DLLs then call the one installed? Or do I have a WindwardPlatform.dll that is built for each so the other DLLs call it by the same name? Or can I have a single DLL that calls the appropiate classes that are built both ways but in the same DLL?

Comment: Try it first please. Such an SDK styled project should yield a NuGet package, not individual assemblies.

Comment: @LexLi Ok, I'm not understanding something. I understand how to have directives to conditionally include/exclude code. But that still leaves what am I targeting. This is one DLL of 12. All the others are .NET Standard (run on Framework & Core). Two of those 12 reference this platform specific DLL. So do I create 2 DLLs and the other code links to either?

Comment: Your description is rather vague. Do you mean this class library will be consumed by 12 other projects? Then what's wrong if this library multitargets net4xx and netstandardxx? With conditional compilation, those other projects can easily consume the necessary APIs from the same NuGet package. A concrete example is at https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/blob/12.0.0/SharpSnmpLib/SharpSnmpLib.csproj

Comment: @LexLi I added a lot more detail above - is that sufficient?

Comment: That's clearer. You should use conditional compilation/multitargeting, and throw `PlatformNotSupportedException` from those methods if targeting netstandardxx. Then your .NET Framework app remains unchanged, while your .NET Core app handles such exceptions. This pattern is widely used by Microsoft.